# Sentry list / count unsent items

Tags: node.js, sentry

I use the "@sentry/node" package and I'd like to know if there's some unsent messages inside the library's queue. As I can see, library's `captureException` and similar functions are synchronous and therefore messages are queued and sent afterwards. I need a way to wait until all messages are sent before I quit my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `await Sentry.flush(timeout)`, or `Sentry.close(timeout)`, see: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/connect/configuration/draining/